# How to swap a 2 digit number and find the larger of the result?

Tags: c#, swap

I want to use the number 25 then swap the two digits (the 2 and the 5) and then compare the swapped number (52) to the first number (25). If the swapped number is bigger I get a true and if the swapped number is smaller than the first number I get a false.

Example of what I want:

Input:

```
25
```

Output:

```
True //Because 25 reversed is 52, so it´s bigger
```

This is what I've tried:

```
        int firstdigit = num / 10;
        int secondigit = num % 10;
        string res = secondigit + firstdigit.ToString();
        
        if(res > num)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
```

The problem now is that the "if" is not working anymore because res is a string and num is an int, but when I make res an int then I cant add the first digit and second digit because it's obviously different if I do 5 + 2 with ints (7) or 5 + 2 with strings (52).

Comment: how about `int res = 10*firstdigit+seconddigit`? there's _no_ need to go the string way at all.

Comment: Would you mind if I posed this as a coding challenge on [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @ouflak If you give me an upvote yea. Just joking it would be cool if you post this as a challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to construct the reversed `int` value and compare against that:

```
int firstdigit = num / 10;
int secondigit = num % 10;
int reversed   = firstdigit + seconddigit * 10;

if (reversed > num)
    ...
```

If you look at the code above, you should see that it's just reversing the logic that you used to extract the first and second digits.

Answer (score 1):

Nice solution.
Maybe that's enough for you

```
int firstdigit = num / 10;
int secondigit = num % 10;

        
        if(secondigit > firstdigit)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
```